# How Windows establishes L2TP/IPSEC VPN connection without "IPSec ID" (group id)?

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec

I have a third-party VPN server configured with only 4 credentials given to me: server ip, preshared key, user name and user password. Under Windows 7, i can easily connect to this VPN via standard "new VPN connection" wizard. But under Linux (Ubuntu etc) if i use `vpnc` client it is asking for "IPSec ID" (group ID) that i need to enter. If i enter empty value, i got "no response from target". If i enter any value, i got "hash comparison failed - check group passsword" error.

How it happens that Windows can establish connection without this "IPSec ID"? Maybe it's some default value available that can be used?

P.S. Also, on OSX "group name" is also marked as "optional" and VPN connection perfectly works without it.

Comment: Are you sure your VPN provider uses L2TP/IPsec (as your title suggests) and not just plain IPsec? (What did you choose on Mac OS X? _Cisco IPsec_?) Because if it does, `vpnc` is not the right client. And even if your provider does not use L2TP `vpnc` will not be able to connect if the provider does not support _Aggressive Mode_, which is the only mode of operation supported by `vpnc`. If the latter is the case you should try a different IPsec client like strongSwan, Openswan, Libreswan, or raccoon.

Comment: In Windows, i select "Cisco L2TP/Ipsec". I'm sure it's something 2-layer since it uses preshared key for secured transport and login/password for some kind of authentication. Where can i read more about this "Aggresive Mode" and another modes of operation?

Comment: @ecdsa Also, i have checked specification and i'm not sure that it's possible to use preshared key in main mode.